# Ubuntu 15.04 running slowly

Tags: boot

This computer had Windows XP, after installation my computer now runs very slow. I removed Windows XP. Is there a way to optimize Ubuntu to get it to run faster?
I have 1.1gig of memory and the cpu is a pentimento 4 2.4GHz.TIA

Answer (score 2):

15.04 has reached its end-of-life date and thus is no longer supported. It's probably better to get either 14.04 or 15.10.

Since your computer is pretty low-spec, something like Lubuntu might be better for you. Lubuntu is Ubuntu, but with a different desktop environment. Instead of Unity, you get LXDE. It looks very different, but it's specifically made to run on computers that aren't very modern, or are just very low budget.

If your computer can support 64-bit, don't get 64-bit Ubuntu. It won't perform very well.

The installation process is pretty much the same as normal Ubuntu.

Lubuntu 14.04 (32-bit): http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/lubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Lubuntu 15.10 (32-bit): http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.10/release/lubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

In your case I will suggest for for lightweight Ubuntu aka lubuntu. Here are more [details](http://lubuntu.net/)